# Displaying item when LVItemGetCaption is being called with EasyListView?

Tags: delphi, listview, virtual

I am trying to implement virtual data mode with [EasyListview](http://www.mustangpeak.net/)

From the demo :

```
procedure TForm1.AddItems(Count: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Add items to the listview. Actually the items are added to the first
  // group. This group is created automatically when the first item is added.
  LV.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
      LV.Items.AddVirtual;
  finally
    LV.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.LVItemGetCaption(Sender: TCustomEasyListview;
  const Item: TEasyItem; Column: Integer; var Caption: WideString);
begin
  case Column of
    0: Caption := 'Item ' + IntToStr(Item.Index);
    1: Caption := 'Detail ' + IntToStr(Item.Index);
  end;
end;
```

If I add some items which are string :

```
procedure TForm1.AddItems(Count: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Add items to the listview. Actually the items are added to the first
  // group. This group is created automatically when the first item is added.
  LV.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      LV.Items.AddVirtual.Caption := 'DISPLAY ME ' + IntToStr(i);
    end;
  finally
    LV.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

How to get and displaying the stored virtual caption(=string) when LVItemGetCaption is being called?

If I get the caption with `Caption := LV.Items.Items[Item.Index].Caption ;` then Stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add your data object to the item. E.g.:

```
type
  TMyData = class
    Caption: string;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  item: TEasyItemVirtual;
  MyData: TMyData;
begin
  EasyListview1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to 100 - 1 do
    begin
      MyData := TMyData.Create;
      MyData.Caption := Format('My Item %D',[i]);
      item := EasyListview1.Items.AddVirtual;
      item.Data := MyData;
    end;
  finally
    EasyListview1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.EasyListview1ItemGetCaption(Sender: TCustomEasyListview; Item: TEasyItem;
  Column: Integer; var Caption: WideString);
begin
  case Column of
    0: Caption := TMyData(Item.Data).Caption;
    1: Caption := TMyData(Item.Data).Caption;
  end;
end;
```

And don't forget to free your object:

```
procedure TForm1.EasyListview1ItemFreeing(Sender: TCustomEasyListview; Item: TEasyItem);
begin
  if Assigned(Item.Data) then
    Item.Data.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Linas, how do I change/update the value of the Caption in virtual nodes? For example, I have a button to change the text from `My Item` become `Your Item` in first record. I only see InsertVirtual method.

Comment: Just cast Item.Data to your type and set caption:   TMyData(EasyListview1.Items[0].Data).Caption := 'Your Item';
  EasyListview1.Items[0].Invalidate(True);.

Answer (score 0):

*Virtual* nodes are ones that don't store their data. They're just *views* of data you are expected to already have in some other data structure of your program. When the control needs to display a node, it asks your program what text it should use by firing the OnItemGetCaption event.

In fact, it will call the event any time it needs to know the value of the Caption property, so when you try to handle the caption-fetching event by fetching the value of the caption, you trigger infinite recursion.

Comment: Can you tell me Rob, what is the bad thing from infinite recursion? So is it a bad idea to use virtual nodes?

Comment: The bad thing from infinite recursion is that you don't have infinite stack space, so you eventually get a stack overflow, as you've observed.

Comment: It's *not* a bad idea to use virtual nodes. It's a terrific idea. But if you do it, you have to realize that the nodes themselves will *not* store your data. That's the whole point. You're expected to already have a data structure where you manage your program's data. The list-view control merely provides a *view* onto that data. Read about the "model-view-controller" pattern in your favorite design-pattern reference.